# How to connect two objects with a laser

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I'm  absolutely new game developer. I created an idea when two objects are connected by laser (which can kills enemies). I'm going to make 2d game. I already downloaded Unity and C#.

Oohh, second question ==> what I need for move the game into Android?
Of course I can study this alone, but i want know this now))  Thanks

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to this path: File > Build Settings...

In the `Build Settings` window select `Android` from the platforms list on the left side, then click the `Switch Platform` button.

[image]